# How can I display a specific user's first published post?

Tags: posts, query, date, publish, id

I'm looking for a way to display a user's first published post using their unique ID.

I have a function that calls a list of specific users using their IDs, and would like to display the date the user first published a post.

This is the code I put in, however, the cells return blank with no PHP errors in the log.

```
$useremail = $ticket['email'];
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
$IDuser = $user->ID; 

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author' => $IDuser,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$first_post = new WP_Query($args);
if ($first_post->have_posts()) {
    $first_post->the_post();

    echo the_time('M j, Y');

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Hi @t f  - its defined just above **$useremail = $ticket['email'];**<br>**$user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );**<br>**$IDuser = $user->ID;**

Tried both publish & ED in case of typo... echo $IDuser returns correct user IDs if I call it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13168/discussion-between-bysander-and-t-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query retrieves the **oldest** post of a specified user/author:

```
$user_id = 42; // or whatever it is
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author' => $user_id,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$first_post = new WP_Query($args);
if ($first_post->have_posts()) {
    $first_post->the_post();

    // Now you can use `the_title();` etc.

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

If you want to show the **first** post a specific user wrote (no matter what the post's publish date is set/altered to), then you have to use `'orderby' => 'ID',`.

Comment: +1 But for `orderby => ID` you'll have to keep in mind that this could as well be a private post, a draft, etc. I'd take the first one, but use `post_status => publish`ed.

Comment: Hi there @kaiser and @t f  - thank you for your responses... I put in the code above `$args = array(
                  'posts_per_page' => 1,
                  'post_status' => 'published',
                  'author' => $IDuser,
                  'orderby' => 'ID',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  );
    $first_post = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($first_post->have_posts()) {
        $first_post->the_post();
        
       echo the_time('M j,Y');
        
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>`

Comment: Changing `$user_id` to the `$IDuser` I have been using, orderby ID as I do want to include any post (draft, automatic etc) and `'post_status => published'` however it returns a blank with no errors in php log... Have I done something wrong here - I used `the_time('M j, Y')` as recommended by another blog when you have multiple entries on a page.

Comment: @t f Good point - have edited into original under EDIT heading

Comment: @Bysander File [edit]s, don't post code in comments. And if you really need to: Format them. Below the button  on the right there's "help".